# .NET Windows Form Events Sequence

Tags: vb.net, events, sequence, loaded

I'm trying to show my Form and after that load my data (what is a little bit slowly).
Even calling my load data methods only on onShown method, my screen stays white until all data are loaded.
[image]

Then I put:

```
Thread.Sleep(100000)
```

In my onShown() method and could notice that when onShown is fired my controls are not loaded (visible).

Is there any event that is raised only when all form controls are loaded and visible?

Tksss...

Answer (score 0):

Do not use thread. It will freeze your window.

The best way to solve these kinds of delay loadings is by using 
`System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`

**Step by step:**

***Step1:***

First add reference `WindowsBase` DLL to your project.

Right click project->Add reference. On the .Net tab select `WindowsBase` and add.

***Step2:***

In the form code Import `Imports System.Windows.threading`

***Step3:***

Create a private object in the form for `DispatcherTimer`

```
Private dispatcherTimer As System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
```

***Step 4:***

In the form "Onshown" event create `DispatcherTimer` object and set the time interval of 2 secs(example).

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        'CREATE DISPATCHER OBJECT
        dispatcherTimer = New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer()

        'ADD THE METHOD TO BE HANDLED AFTER SPECIFIED INTERVAL
        AddHandler dispatcherTimer.Tick, AddressOf dispatcherTimer_Tick

        'SET YOUR INTERVAL  (set 2 sec for example)
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 2)

        'START THE TIMER.
        dispatcherTimer.Start()
    End Sub
```

And in the method `dispatcherTimer_Tick` (Handler added in the above method) load your form controls

```
   Public Sub dispatcherTimer_Tick()
            Try
                TextBox1.Text = "example"
                TextBox2.Text = "example"
                TextBox3.Text = "example"
                TextBox4.Text = "example"

               'CALL STOP TO THE TIMER SO THAT THE "dispatcherTimer_Tick" WONT GET CALLED REPEATEDLY.
                dispatcherTimer.Stop()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End Sub
```